# Solve an equation with quadratics

Tags: quadratic-forms

I'm having problems solving the following equation for $\frac{q}{R}$:
$$\left(\frac{q}{R}sin\phi\right)^2 + \left(\frac{q}{R}cos\phi - \frac{b}{R}\right)^2sin^2\theta = 1 $$

Edit:  Based on the suggestion from Ninad Munshi, I am using the quadratic equation to try and solve this problem. Writing out the formula so that I can put it in the form of $ax^2 + bx + c = 0$ yields:

$$\frac{q^2}{R^2}sin^2\phi + \frac{q^2}{R^2}cos^2\phi sin^2\theta - \frac{2qbcos\phi sin^2\theta}{R^2} + \frac{b^2}{R^2}sin^2\theta - 1 = 0 $$

Now putting this eqn in the quadratic form where x = $\frac{q}{R}$:

$$(sin^2\phi + cos^2\phi sin^2\theta)\frac{q^2}{R^2} - \left(\frac{2bcos\phi sin^2\theta}{R}\right)\frac{q}{R} + \left(\frac{b^2}{R^2}sin^2\theta - 1\right) = 0 $$

Now with:

$$a = (sin^2\phi + cos^2\phi sin^2\theta) $$

$$b= - \left(\frac{2bcos\phi sin^2\theta}{R}\right)$$

$$c= \left(\frac{b^2}{R^2}sin^2\theta - 1\right)$$

So:
$$\frac{q}{R} = \frac{\frac{2bcos\phi sin^2\theta}{R}\pm\sqrt{\frac{4b^2cos^2\phi sin^4\theta}{R^2}-4(sin^2\phi + cos^2\phi sin^2\theta)\left(\frac{b^2}{R^2}sin^2\theta - 1\right)}}{2(sin^2\phi + cos^2\phi sin^2\theta)} $$

Multiplying out under the square root sign:

$$\frac{q}{R} = \frac{\frac{2bcos\phi sin^2\theta}{R}\pm\sqrt{\frac{4b^2cos^2\phi sin^4\theta}{R^2}-\frac{4sin^2\phi b^2sin^2\theta}{R^2} - \frac{4b^2cos^2\phi sin^4\theta}{R^2} +4sin^2\phi + 4cos^2\phi sin^2\theta}}{2(sin^2\phi + cos^2\phi sin^2\theta)} $$

Simplifying:

$$\frac{q}{R} = \frac{\frac{bcos\phi sin^2\theta}{R}\pm\sqrt{-\frac{b^2sin^2\phi sin^2\theta}{R^2}  +sin^2\phi + cos^2\phi sin^2\theta}}{(sin^2\phi + cos^2\phi sin^2\theta)} $$

Now I'm stuck. It seems like it should be possible to simplify further.

Comment: I think you mightve taken it too far. After expanding the first line you can just use quadratic equation.

Comment: MathJax hint:  if you put a backslash before common functions you get the right font and spacing, so \sin x gives $\sin x$ instead of sin x giving $sin x$

Answer (score 0):

In the first place, without further contexts provided, I assumed that both $q$ and $R$ are unknown so you tried to solve for the ratio instead. In that case, the solution is not ideal as it contains the variable $R$. However, it might also be the fact that $R$ is a constant and you solve for $\frac{q}{R}$ for the convenience of the task that you are working on. It is an important item that you are recommended to get clear about, if not yet, before moving on.

Here is my suggestion for further simplification.
$$\frac{q}{R}=\frac{\frac{b\cos\phi\sin^2\theta}{R}\pm\sqrt{-\frac{b^2\sin^2\phi\sin^2\theta}{R^2}+\sin^2\phi+\cos^2\phi\sin^2\theta}}{\sin^2\phi+\cos^2\phi\sin^2\theta}\\
=\frac{b\cos\phi\sin^2\theta\pm\sqrt{-b^2\sin^2\phi\sin^2\theta+R^2(\sin^2\phi+\cos^2\phi\sin^2\theta)}}{R(\sin^2\phi+\cos^2\phi\sin^2\theta)}\\
=\frac{b\cos\phi\sin^2\theta\pm\sqrt{\cos^2\phi\times[-b^2\tan^2\phi\sin^2\theta+R^2(\tan^2\phi+\sin^2\theta)]}}{R\cos^2\phi(\tan^2\phi+\sin^2\theta)}\\
=\underline{\underline{\frac{b\sin^2\theta\pm\sqrt{-b^2\tan^2\phi\sin^2\theta+R^2(\tan^2\phi+\sin^2\theta)}}{R\cos\phi(\tan^2\phi+\sin^2\theta)}}}$$

I believe this simplification is more for aesthetical effect than a real reduction in computation effort.

1. It slightly reduces the number of trigonometric functions by the use of $\tan$.
2. It better aligns the degrees of the trigonometric functions -- most of them are of degree two.
3. It avoids nested fractions.

Comment: I am trying to follow a derivation in a technical paper where they just give a final answer.  Ultimately, the expression $\frac{q}{R}$ is used in the following integral:
$$\pi \cot\theta = \int_{0}^{\pi}\left(\frac{q}{R}\right)^2\cos\phi d\phi$$

Comment: These authors never mention what the expression was for $\frac{q}{R}$ that they used in the integral. They only say that they derived a suitable expression for $\frac{q}{R}$ from the original equation that I gave in my post.  Surprisingly to me, the result of the integration is:
$$\frac{b}{R} = \cot\theta$$

BTW: $\theta$ is a constant, R is a constant and b is a constant, q varies as does $\phi$.  Ultimately I'm trying to determine b or $\frac{b}{R}$ is fine.